# Force Remove Phpmyadmin and PHP7.0 Sub-process Error

Tags: php, python, mysql, django, phpmyadmin

I'm just tired of PHP7.0 forcing itself on me! I've deleted all files relating to php7.0 on my VPS and I've tried uninstalling it with different command lines yet it will bring up the below error..even after I deleted its folders.

I wanted to install supervisor but I couldn't because of the below error that PHP is still printing out. I Don't want to use PHPMyAdmin and PHP7 anymore.!

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

What am I missing to clear this?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
supervisor is already the newest version (3.2.0-2ubuntu0.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up php7.0-fpm (7.0.18-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1) ...
Not replacing deleted config file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
Job for php7.0-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error                                                                              code. See "systemctl status php7.0-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details                                                                             .
invoke-rc.d: initscript php7.0-fpm, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-fpm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of phpmyadmin:
 phpmyadmin depends on libapache2-mod-php | libapache2-mod-phpfilter | php-cgi |                                                                              php-fpm | php; however:
  Package libapache2-mod-php is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php7.0 which provides libapache2-mod-php is not install                                                                             ed.
  Package libapache2-mod-phpfilter is not installed.
  Package php-cgi is not installed.
  Package php-fpm is not installed.
  Package php7.0-fpm which provides php-fpm is not configured yet.
  Package php is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
  Errors were enco2untered while processing:
 php7.0-fpm
 phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to remove it with this command.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge php7.0
```

I removed the package one by one.